# Why can I scroll down, but I can't up

Tags: html, css

this code allows you to scroll the element up and down, however, the indents behave strangely, for example, the first option is the indents from the bottom in order, but from the top they are outside the container.

```css
.block{
height: 10vmin;
width: 20vmin;
background: green;

font-size: 2vmin;
padding: 1vmin;
color: white;

display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;

overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="block">
123321123321123 2123123 213123123123 213123123123 123123123123 123123123123 21321231231231 213123123123 213231231231 12312312312 1231231231 2213223123123123 123123123123123 </div>
<body>
```

[image: 1]
How can I make it so that if there is no scroll, the element is in the middle and the paddings behave correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `flex-wrap: wrap;` to `.block`;

```css
.block{
height: 10vmin;
width: 20vmin;
background: green;

font-size: 2vmin;
padding: 1vmin;
color: white;

display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;

overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;

flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="block">
123321123321123 2123123 213123123123 213123123123 123123123123 123123123123 21321231231231 213123123123 213231231231 12312312312 1231231231 2213223123123123 123123123123123 </div>
</body>
```